# Node.JS HTTP Request Timeout

Tags: node.js

I have an app that will require HTTP requests to a primary and secondary URL.  When the primary URL goes down I need to be able to handle this gracefully and failover to the secondary URL.  I already have the failover function running, but am running into an issue handling the timeouts.

After some searching I found that Node does not have a default timeout so I have set one up.  The problem I am running into is that after setting the request time out that the socket stays open.  If I destroy or abort the request it throws an error that it was exited too soon.  I know that I can handle this with a req.on('error'), but I want to be able to use that for other error handling as well if necessary.  I have tried a couple of ways of running the time out.

The first is to set a timeout on the socket and destroy it.  This causes a socket hang up error.

```
var req= https.request(options, function(res){
    //Handle response based on return code
});


req.on('socket', function(socket){
     socket.setTimeout(10000);
     socket.on('timeout', function(){
         socket.destroy();
          self.emit("runAgain");
     })
});

req.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
}); 

req.end();
```

The other way I tried is to set a time out on the request.  This caused an ECONNRESET error.

```
req.setTimeout(100, function(){
   req.destroy();
   console.log('request destroyed');
})
```

I'm looking for the best way to handle this so that I don't have to set a time out and then catch an error if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could just subscribe to your own "runAgain" event that you are emitting, maybe keep a counter around or something:

```
self.madeSecondaryRequest = false;

self.on("runAgain", function() {
    if(!self.madeSecondaryRequest) {
        console.log("Hey I could make my request again!");
        self.madeSecondaryRequest = true;
    }
});
```